# Image LazyLoad plugin not loading jQuery dependancies with wp_enqueue_script in WP 3.3.1

Tags: images, jquery, customization, wp-enqueue-script

I am attempting to install the image [LazyLoad](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/) plugin with use on my Wordpress 3.3.1 blog.

I have followed the basic instructions, so it is installed and activated on my development site.

The problem is I see no jQuery.sonar reference in the source (which this plugin uses).

The plugin does this when en queuing the scripts:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpcom-lazy-load-images',  self::get_url( 'js/lazy-load.js' ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-sonar' ), self::version, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-sonar', self::get_url( 'js/jquery.sonar.min.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), self::version, true );
```

Why would these scripts not be output and available in the source?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. Are you using any other plugins? Perhaps a caching plugin that does minification or some such thing?

Comment: @Otto I am using other plugins, but no caching ones.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, without more information, the problem cannot be solved then. Like I said, there's nothing wrong with that code. So the problem must be in some other code in your setup.

Comment: @Otto I ended up abandoning the idea of a WP plugin an used jQuery Unveil instead http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Answer (score 0):

It's better check if your minify plugin ( eg:- W3 total) minify or combined jQuery.sonar file. That's why you can't see it.